# Open Pdf with Specific page?

Tags: c#, pdf, file-io

How to open PDF File with Specific page in C#.net. I do not want to use AcroRd32.exe in code because  there is different version install on user machine.and different version have different .exe file so how I can open pdf with Specific page using C#?

Comment: are you wanting to pull the data or actually open and display the PDF to a user?

Comment: open and display the pdf to user.

Answer (score 0):

You should view some parametter in here http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#page=2

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
startInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/A page={0} {1}", page, file);
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: look at pretty much any high rated answer on this site - whatever code there is is usually accompanied by an explanation. It's the same reasoning behind commenting your code. In your case, explain what the issue is and how your code solves it, instead of just providing code. The code solves the issue today, but doesn't teach the person asking the question or future viewers *why* the issue was solved, or how to solve variants.

Comment: looking back at answers to my questions, none of the answers given meet your criteria.